# How can I use NSTimer with this simple while loop?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nstimer

I have a -(void) method being executed and at one point it gets to a while loop that gets values from the accelerometer directly the moment it asks for them

I went throughout the documentation regarding the NSTimer class but I couldn't make sense of how exactly I am to use this object in my case :

e.g.

```
-(void) play
{
    ......
    ...



    if(accelerationOnYaxis >0 && accelerationOnYaxis < 0.9 )
    {
        startTimer;
    }

    while(accelerationOnYaxis >0 && accelerationOnYaxis < 0.9)
    {
        if(checkTimer >= 300msec)
        {

           printOut_AccelerationStayedBetweenThoseTwoValuesForAtLeast300msecs;
           break_Out_Of_This_Loop;
        }

    }

    stopTimerAndReSetTimerToZero;

    .....
    more code...
    ....
    ...
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it with `NSTimer`, because it needs your code to exit in order to fire. `NSTimer` uses the event loop to decide when to call you back; if your program holds the control in its `while` loop, there is no way for the timer to fire, because the code that checks if it's time to fire or not is never reached.

On top of that, staying in a busy loop for nearly a second and a half is going to deplete your battery. If you simply need to wait for `1.4s`, you are better off calling `sleepForTimeInterval:`, like this:

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.4];
```

You can also use [`clock()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/) from `<time.h>` to measure short time intervals, like this:

```
clock_t start = clock();
clock_t end = start + (3*CLOCKS_PER_SEC)/10; // 300 ms == 3/10 s
while(accelerationOnYaxis >0 && accelerationOnYaxis < 0.9)
{
    if(clock() >= end)
    {
       printOut_AccelerationStayedBetweenThoseTwoValuesForAtLeast300msecs;
       break_Out_Of_This_Loop;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm running my -(void) play method in a separate thread if that makes any difference to what you're saying, given that I'm new to Obj-C.. :)

Comment: @SproutCoder Running on a separate thread does not help. `NSTimer` is merely a scheduling mechanism that lets you stick pieces of code to be executed in the run loop after a predefined time interval; they do not somehow preempt execution of your code, so if you're in a busy loop, you're not going to see a timer fire.

Comment: I re-edited my original post to give you a more concrete idea of what I'm trying to do (I'll be using values coming from the accelerometer directly in real-time, each time I get to my while loop's condition)..

Comment: @SproutCoder I see what you're trying to do. Please take a look at the update to the answer.

Comment: great, I'll try that! Talking about time : given the code you suggested, if the condition of my while loop stays true, the loop will execute for around 300msec, right? But while, the loop is executing, other stuff are being executed in my iPhone at the "same" time, which is not the same time is it? Nothing happens in parallel unless there are at least 2 processors on the iPhone. So the loop won't execute for 300msecs, right? It will be interrupted by other stuff happening inside the iPhone right? So 300 msecs isn't 100% true is it? It's 300msecs+ (even if it's + a few micro/nano secs..)

Comment: @SproutCoder Absolutely, the timing in iOS is not precise. There is a nice article about precision timing in iOS ([link](http://atastypixel.com/blog/experiments-with-precise-timing-in-ios/)).

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out. The reason I asked about it is because I was afraid that running a loop based on a timer might mean that the device's processor sacrifices all of its "energy" to that tiny loop of mine for those 300 msecs or so, which would obviously be a very inefficient way for an app to function (causing all kinds of problems to the rest of the device's needs..)

Comment: @SproutCoder If using too much CPU becomes an issue, you can throttle your loop by inserting small delays using `sleepForTimeInterval:`.

Comment: I just realized that the clock() code you suggested is in c++. I'm writing code in Objective-C for an iOS app. How is that going to work?

Comment: @SproutCoder The link is to C++ reference web site, but the code is straight C. Don't forget to include `<time.h>`.

Comment: so if I include <time.h> in my .m file where the above -(void) play will be, I can use the code you suggested and it will compile into a working iPhone app?

Comment: @SproutCoder Yes, this should compile and run fine under iOS. Did you get a chance to try it?

Answer (score 1):

`NSTimer` works a little different than you want. What you need is a counter for your timer, to get how many times it looped. If your counter gets on 14 (if it's an integer), you can invalidate it.

```
//start timer
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
        target:self
        selector:@selector(play:)
        userInfo:nil
        repeats:YES];

//stop timer
[timer invalidate];
```

You can create your function without that while.

```
- (void)play {
    ......
    ...


    counter++; //declare it in your header

    if(counter < 14){
        x++; //your integer needs to be declared in your header to keep it's value
    } else {
        [timer invalidate];
    }

    useValueofX;
}
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

Comment: I've edited my original post, please have a look at my comment to dasBlinkenLight if you want :)

Comment: Can you be more specific? Try to explain what your app will do, or your idea. From all we have, it's complicated to help you.

Comment: I will create a method that will return the force exercised on the Y-axis of the accelerometer, at the time that method is called, as a double . I will then use that method (i.e. the double it returns) inside the condition of my while loop, like I do in my example. If that condition stays true for at least 300 msecs, I will then break from the loop and move on.. That's it. By the way, I'm obviously using pseudocode in parts of my example, I know it's not valid Obj-C. :)